# How can I test a cell's edited value against it's original value?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a spreadsheet where default values are provided to the user. I have these formatted plainly (white background/black text).

I set up a macro to format cells as highlighted (yellow background/bold text) when the value has been edited.

I'm trying to capture the original value (or Value2?) of each cell, upon entering it, so that if a user changes the value it will highlight the cell with the conditional formatting macro I set up BUT if they revert the value to what was there originally the highlighting goes away.

For example, I have a "First Name" column with a "Stephen" cell in it. If the user edits that cell to say "Joe" it will become highlighted to show that it has been edited and is no longer the default value. If the user then edits the cell to once again say "Stephen" the new value would match the original, unedited value, and the conditional formatting (highlighting) will be removed.

I've read some tutorials [here](https://powerspreadsheets.com/excel-vba-value-value2/#VBA-code-to-get-cell-value) but the tutorials without modifying to meet my needs were throwing errors.

I tried setting the value to a variable but it doesn't seem to be helping.

```
Dim myCellValue As Variant
myCellSetValue.Value = Range.Value2
```

This is the macro I have in place now. It changes the formatting of every cell as soon as it's clicked into, regardless of editing.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 36
    Target.Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
End Sub
```

I need to
1. apply this formatting only if the value is changed
2. remove this formatting if the cell's value matches it's original value

Also, is there a way to 'one click revert' the cell to it's original value?

Comment: You need to keep the original values somewhere separate, then comparison testing is easy and so is reversion.

Comment: you can achieve this with a hidden column (or row) with all the default values. the rest is conditional formating to see if the value is unequal to the default

Comment: Use `Selection_Change` in the worksheet to record your current value, and then `Change` to check, so set say `varWas` in Selection_Change and `varTo` in Change, and then compare the two.

Comment: @SolarMike when you say somewhere separate in a different Sub? or just setting the Dim outside of a Sub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this as a base

```
Public varWas As Variant
Public varTo As Variant

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    varTo = Target.Value
    If varTo = varWas Then
        Target.Interior.Color = vbWhite
        Target.Font.Bold = False
    Else
        Target.Interior.Color = vbRed
        Target.Font.Bold = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    varWas = Target.Value
End Sub
```

**** UPDATE ****

in a standard module, create the following

```
Public arrContentsAtStart As Variant
Public rngChecked As Range

Public Sub setup()
    Set rngChecked = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    arrContentsAtStart = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value
End Sub
```

and then in the worksheet module add the following, you will need to run set up on workbook open I imagine, it's up to you though when to get the "as is" data.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, rngChecked) Is Nothing Then

        If Target.Value <> arrContentsAtStart(Target.Row, Target.Column) Then

            '   Value change format accordingly
            Target.Font.Bold = True

        ElseIf Target.Value = arrContentsAtStart(Target.Row, Target.Column) Then

            '   Reverted back to original value format accordingly

            Target.Font.Bold = False

        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This works great except that it sets the varWas variable to whatever is initially in the cell **when clicked**, I need to set and store the variable only once. so if a cell's original value is "xyz" and a user edits it to "abc" it highlights, but if the user resets the value back to "xyz" then, and only then does the highlighting go away. So is there a way to set that varWas value only the first time the user clicks into the cell, and not every time?

Comment: Thanks, this works even better. My only issue now is trying to run setup() on workbook_open is throwing errors.

I've tried

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Call setup
End Sub 

and it throws an error on line 2 of the worksheet module, maybe not finding the rngChecked variable?
Same result when I put the setup code directly in the workbook open Sub like this:

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set rngChecked = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    arrContentsAtStart = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
End Sub

Comment: You gave it 20mins :o)   What errors?  Maybe the activesheet references.

Answer (score 0):

We can use column **XFD** as the "memory" of the original values in column **A**.

**First** enter all original values in column **A**.
**Second** enter this into a standard module and run it:

```
Public A As Range
Public XFD As Range
Public setup As String

Public Sub Initialize()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Set A = Range("A:A")
        Set XFD = Range("XFD:XFD")
        A.Copy XFD
        setup = "done"
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

**Third** enter this into the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Intersekt As Range, r As Range

    If setup <> "done" Then Exit Sub
    Set Intersekt = Intersect(A, Target)
    If Intersekt Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    For Each r In Intersekt
        If r.Value = XFD(r.Row) Then
            r.ClearFormats
        Else
            r.Interior.Color = 65535
            r.Font.Bold = True
        End If
    Next r

End Sub
```